# What action do I need to fall prone

Tags: pathfinder-1e, actions

I am looking for information what action I have to use when I want to go prone like lay flat on the floor. I can as a swift action stand up from prone and want to duck behind a table stand up shoot fall prone again. Just in case it is a swift action, can I interchange a swift with a move action? So I can use my swift to stand up, a standard to shoot and a move to fall prone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **In Pathfinder 1E, its a free action to fall prone**

Per the CRB pg188:

> Dropping to a prone position in your space is a free action.

For your second question, you can take a move action in place of a standard action, but you cannot take a swift action in place of any other action type. Actions and how you can interchange them are discussed in the Core Rulebook starting on page 181. You can also find this information on [Archives of Nethys for Pathfinder 1E](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Action%20Types&Category=Actions%20in%20Combat).